# In QGIS what files do I need to recreate this map?

Tags: qgis

http://gaez.fao.org/Main.html#

I am trying to use the maps on this website in my QGIS project. When I download the zip it comes with a few different types of files but I do not know which ones to use to make it look like the preview.

Here is a image of the zip:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit unclear on your question. Are you not sure which file to open? I think you want to open the TIF file.

Layer-> Add Layer -> Add Raster Layer

Then under Source -> Raster Dataset(s) click on the "..." then browse to where you have the files saved and add the TIF file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did that but it shows up as just black and gray while the map on the website is orange to green. It also comes with a spreadsheet where the values for each color are attached and I need those to all be together in a layer.

Comment: You need to adjust the symbology: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html

Comment: This website may be more helpful: https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/creating-a-qgis-color-map-from-text-file/